# Diacritical marks in tags page

Tags: bug, tags, design, localization

Tags page displays diacritical marks from not visible line of tag excerpt, e.g.:

- [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags)

> [image: ru]

- [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags)

> [image: pt]

Same for [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags) and [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags) SO.

Comment: looks like the css needs to be  `.excerpt: {height: 3em;}` instead of 39px;

Comment: Isn't it fixed yet? I can't find any of them

Comment: @vp_arth still is issue, tested on Chrome and FF just now!

Comment: Yes, It just hard to detect them. Now I see)

Comment: We're looking into this to see how we can fix it. The way we cut off those tag boxes is sub-optimal (based on px height), so fixing it will require addressing that.