# All Stack Exchange sites page in grid mode contains parts of names

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com

[All Stack Exchange sites page](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid#) contains parts of site's names if name does not fit into block:

> [image: grid view]

Comment: [Same effect for tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290936/339911) not yet fixed.

Comment: Clearly not *all* of them... The ones you haven't circled are perfectly fine. :P

Comment: The problem isn't the styling. The problem here is that we're pulling the full name including "Stack Exchange" when we should just use the short form instead.

Comment: @AdamLear I'm not sure how that's not [tag:design], but if you believe it should go, then so be it.

Comment: @yo' See my answer. Not a design issue, though it sort of presents as one.

Comment: @AdamLear Yeah I saw and I would still classify it as a design issue. Probably just a word meaning discrepancy.

Comment: @yo' I just tend to look at it in the context of "the content is correct and is what we want to display, but there is a style problem that needs an actual designer to look at". :)

Comment: @AdamLear Yeah, I got it afterwards. For you a [tag:design] [tag:bug] is something a "designer" (or CSS styler or so) has to look into, not a "programmer".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bad - I fixed this on the list view of All Sites a while back, but didn't think to check the grid as well.

A build is rolling out now that removes "Stack Exchange" from the names of sites.